# Authenticating remote access to Sharepoint 2016 on-premises via REST API

Tags: jquery, ajax, sharepoint, cors, fiddler

I am trying to connect a remote web application to a on premise SharePoint 2016 solution. I am stuck on authenticating so I can access a list from SharePoint. It only has to be read only.

Here is my call (generated from Postman):

```
var settings = {
"async": true,
"method": "POST",
"url": "http://mycompanywebsite/sites/home/_api/Web/Lists('guid'55a15262-34d5-4b5c-aec9-27fdc1c02589')",

"headers": {
"X-RequestDigest": "Unique ID Here",
"Content-Type":'application/json'
 }
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function(response){
console.log(response);
});
```

Any attempt was met with a "401 Authorized" error. Using Fiddler's "Automatically Authenticate" feature, I was able to get different results:

**Attempt A.)
Updating the web.config file on the server by adding custom headers with the below:**

```
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://localhost:1234" />
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS" />
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true"/>
```

This results in:

```
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*
```

**Attempt B.) 
Updating the web.config file on the server by enabling "Access-Control-Allow_Origin with just these below:**

```
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
```

This results in:

```
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*
```

**Attempt C.)
I added "crossDomain": true attribute to the AJAX call above.**

```
"crossDomain": true,
```

This results in:

```
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*
```

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong here. I am able to access the internal SharePoint without any problems, access the SharePoint URL that I'm trying the authenticate to, but nothing.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, have you found a solution to this yet?

Comment: see if this helps https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/210179/how-to-allow-authenticated-cross-domain-calls-in-an-sp-2016-on-prem-scenario and https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9ae5ea28-5e46-4192-953d-d6142b1d060a/cors-change-in-sharepoint-server-2016?forum=SP2016

Answer (score -1):

This problem usually related to the backend server, but if you don't have an access to the server so you have two options

**First option** to use this chrome extension: [Allow-Control-Allow-Origin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en) but unfortunately, this extension is not available in the other browsers so you need to use

**Second option** by using online CORS proxy like

https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://example.com

http://cors-proxy.htmldriven.com/?url=http://www.htmldriven.com/sample.json

> CORS proxy is a free service for developers who need to bypass same-origin policy related to performing standard AJAX requests to 3rd party services.

Here's a full example of Ajax request

```
  $.ajax({
            url: 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://example.com',
            type: 'POST',
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'bearer t-7614f875-8423-4f20-a674-d7cf3096290e');
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
            },
            headers: {
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*",
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json',
           }
            xhrFields: {
                    'withCredentials': true
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            crossDomain: true
            data: {},
            success: function () { },
            error: function () { },
            });

        });

    });
```

I added `withCredentials()` it makes your browser include cookies and authentication headers in your XHR request. If your service depends on any cookie (including session cookies), it will only work with this option set.

Comment: withCredentials won't work with Sharepoint 2016 rest api and the url rewrite in iis doesn't seem to work either, seems the only solution is to call a web api that calls to the sharepoint 2016 api

Comment: Have you tried to use chrome extension: Allow-Control-Allow-Origin?

Comment: yes, I think the security has changed in sharepoint because works with 2013 but did read the security model has changed with the web services. It works fine  inside of sharepoint so  the best solution is to create a custom web api and call sharepoint from the server side which works. Thanks